# What does pss mean in /proc/pid/smaps

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, linux-kernel

I was confused about the `Pss` column in `/proc/pid/smaps`, so I wrote a program to test it:

```c
void sa();
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int fd;
    sa();
    sleep(1000);
}

void sa()
{
   char *pi=new char[1024*1024*10];
   for(int i=0;i<4;++i) {
        for(int j=0;j<1024*1024;++j){
                *pi='o';
                pi++;
        }
   }
   int cnt;
   for(int i=0;i<6;++i) {
        for(int j=0;j<1024*1024;++j){
                cnt+=*pi;
                pi++;
        }
   }
   printf("%d",cnt);
}
```

```
$cat /proc/`pidof testprogram`/smaps

08838000-0885b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
Size:                140 kB
Rss:                  12 kB
Pss:                  12 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:        12 kB
Referenced:           12 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
b6dcd000-b77d0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
Size:              10252 kB
Rss:               10252 kB
Pss:                4108 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:      4108 kB
Referenced:         4108 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
```

Here I found `Pss` equal to `Private_Dirty`, but I wonder why.

BTW: Is there any detailed documentation for `smaps`?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Quoting from [lwn.net](http://lwn.net/Articles/230975/)

> The "proportional set size" (PSS) of a process is the count of pages
>   it has in memory, where each page is divided by the number of
>   processes sharing it. So if a process has 1000 pages all to itself,
>   and 1000 shared with one other process, its PSS will be 1500

From [Linux Kernel Documentation](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt),

The `/proc/PID/smaps` is an extension based on maps, showing the memory
    consumption for each of the process's mappings. For each of mappings there
    is a series of lines such as the following:

```
08048000-080bc000 r-xp 00000000 03:02 13130      /bin/bash
Size:               1084 kB
Rss:                 892 kB
Pss:                 374 kB
Shared_Clean:        892 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:         0 kB
Referenced:          892 kB
Anonymous:             0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
Locked:              374 kB
```

> The first of these lines shows the same information as is displayed
>   for the mapping in **/proc/PID/maps**.  The remaining lines show the size
>   of the mapping (**size**), the amount of the mapping that is currently
>   resident in RAM (**RSS**), the process' proportional share of this mapping
>   (**PSS**), the number of clean and dirty private pages in the mapping. 
>   Note that even a page which is part of a **MAP_SHARED** mapping, but has
>   only a single pte mapped, i.e.  is currently used by only one process,
>   is accounted as private and not as shared.  "**Referenced**" indicates the
>   amount of memory currently marked as referenced or accessed.
>   "**Anonymous**" shows the amount of memory that does not belong to any
>   file.  Even a mapping associated with a file may contain anonymous
>   pages: when **MAP_PRIVATE** and a page is modified, the file page is
>   replaced by a private anonymous copy. "**Swap**" shows how much
>   would-be-anonymous memory is also used, but out on swap.

[This Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33381/getting-information-about-a-process-memory-usage-from-proc-pid-smaps) on `Unix and Linux` Stackexchange covers almost the topic. See Mat's excellent answer which will surely clear all your doubts.

Comment: Why do I see many PSS, when I run the smaps on my binary. Here is the output of one of the binary -Locked:0 kB 77afd000-77afe000 r--p 00007000 00:0e 20581089  /lib/ld-uClibc-0.9.33.2.so. Do I need to add all the PSS to actually compute the size taken up by the binary. Is this size equal to the size occupied in the RAM?
Size: 4 kB Rss:  4 kB Pss: 4 kB Private_Dirty: 4 kB Referenced: 4 kB
Anonymous: 4 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
77ab2000-77ad6000 r-xp 00000000 00:0e 20711467   /usr/lib/libdbus-glib-1.so.2.2.0
Size:                144 kB
Rss:                 112 kB
Pss:                  12 kB